# Firefox prints second page blank

Tags: html, css, firefox, printing

Hello I've a HTML page and I want to print it on 2 pages, but when I print it in Firefox the first page is ok and the second is blank.
I've try to print the page with different printers and PDF, I've always the same problem.
I've try Firefox for macOsx an it has the same problem.
In other browsers (IExplorer and Safari) works fine.

this is the code:

```
        <div id="corpo_centrale"> 
        <div id="contenitore_misure_stampa">
            <div id="sfondo_misure_stampa">
            <img src="images/stampa-risultati-1.jpg" width="1026"/>
            </div>
            <div id="misure_stampa">
            some text
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="page-break-after:always"></div>
        <div id="contenitore_risultato_stampa">
            <div id="sfondo_risultato_stampa">
            <img src="images/stampa-risultati-2.jpg" width="1026" />
            </div>
            <div id="risultato_stampa">
            some text
            </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

This is CSS

```
#contenitore_misure_stampa {
    position: relative;
    width: 1026px;
    height: 1451px; 
}

#contenitore_risultato_stampa {
    position: relative;
    width: 1026px;
    height: 1451px; 
}

#sfondo_misure_stampa {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    width: 1026px;
    height: 1451px; 
}

#misure_stampa {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 1026px;
    height: 1451px; 
}

#sfondo_risultato_stampa {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1026px;
    height: 1451px; 
}

#risultato_stampa {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 1026px;
    height: 1451px; 
}
```

Comment: TO be honest: You probably completely over-engineered the CSS of the page. Hard coded width/height in pixels and absolute positioning is generally a bad thing, especially if you want to print. Drop all of that and see if it works. In any case re-write the CSS avoiding both of those things. It seems you want to use backgroundimages.

Comment: OK I've simplified my css and HTML code and now it works fine. Thanks